# Website is not redirecting to respective domain name

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, migration, server-setup, hosting

When the site (only database not the full theme) is migrated to hosting environment(Nexcess) and even after changing the base urls in the `core_config_data` the site is not available. It is displaying error like **`The page isn’t working`**.

**Note**: when I give some other domain name in the `core_config_data` it is finely redirecting with respect to the provided domain name. Only one particular url is not working and displaying error.

So is there anything that should be done at the admin panel after moving the site to hosting environment? Or is there anything I should do additionally to redirect to my site's link?

Answer (score 1):

There was a space at beginning of the url. When I removed the space before the  entered secure and unsecure url at admin panel(system/configuration->web/secure & unsecure url) the url redirection was very fine.

This may not be a great answer to post but I hope it may help someone struggling to figure out what was the problem going on when it is just a spacing issue.